# Creating subset of a Set in Java

Tags: java, set, subset, linkedhashset

I have a  `LinkedHashSet`, i.e an ordered set. I'm trying to find a function to just return a subset of the set, i.e the first 20 elements of the set. I know I can do it by creating a new set and then populating using an iteration of the first set but I was hoping for something more succinct.

Also took a look at Google's Guava libraries, but couldn't see what I wanted.

Comment: If you can use `SortedSet` then you already have a method to take subset out of it..

Comment: SortedSet is no good as their natural ordering is not what I want I want their insertion order ordering

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In Guava:

```
Set<Integer> subset = ImmutableSet.copyOf(Iterables.limit(set, 20));
```

Note that `Iterables.limit()` is evaluated lazily, so only one extra collection is created.

Comment: Thanks I had an inkling there would be a way to do this in guava.

Comment: what if I want get from index 20-40?

Comment: @Dejell As you have already figured out by now, there is no index in `Set` unless its implementation has one e.g. `SortedSet`

Answer (score 28):

In Java 8 you can do

```
mySet.stream()
   .skip(start) // the offset
   .limit(count) // how many items you want
   .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 24):

A solution using streams and collectors:

```
Set<Integer> subSet = set.stream()
    // .skip(10) // Use this to get elements later in the stream
    .limit(20)
    .collect(toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
    // You could also collect to something else 
    // with another collector like this: 
    // .collect(toList());
```

This assumes the following import:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toCollection;
```

Comment: You mean limit() not skip() I think.

Answer (score 18):

You could do this:

```
Set<Integer> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
   set.add(i);
}

List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(set);
Set<Integer> subSet = new LinkedHashSet<>(list.subList(0, 20));
```

Comment: THanks that look neat, except for the fact you have to create both another Set and an ArrayList but I can live with that.

Comment: To avoid a `IndexOutOfBoundsException` use `Math.min(list.size(), 20)` as 2nd parameter of `subList` in case of a dynamically filled list.

Answer (score 5):

You can either use at first a `SortedSet` as the [`subSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html#subSet%28E,%20E%29) method exists on it.

You can also add the content of your set to a `List` and use the `subList` method on it. But it depends on the amount of data stored in your `Set` as you would not want to duplicate an enormous volume of data.

Otherwise you should stay with the iteration over the Set as it will be more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Simple helper method (You can use it for Set or any other collection):

```
public static <T> List<T> listOf(final Collection<T> set, final int limit) {
    final List<T> list = new ArrayList<>(limit);

    final Iterator<T> i = set.iterator();
    for (int j = 0; j < limit && i.hasNext(); j++) {
        list.add(i.next());
    }

    return list;
}
```